# Buffer with TL084CN and resistors

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, resistors, buffer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWeCB7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are two buffers made with the TL084CN, which is part of the conditioning of an LTS25-P transformer. Currently, I have put a 100ohm resistor in the non-inverting input, and the feedback is without the resistor.

Is it advisable to add a resistor in feedback? Will the reading be influenced if I do not?

Comment: What circuit?  You can edit your question and add a diagram using the built in circuit editor.

Comment: How bad is the layout? Could there be appreciable capacitance to GND at the - pin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary: For your case and your sensor is not important. your 100ohm resistance is negligible.

when your input resistance (\$100\:\Omega\$) * Input Offset Current_max (\$20\:\text{nA}\$) in the worst case generate \$2\:\mu\text{V}\$ offset voltage, your opamp typical input offset is in range \$3\:\text{mV}\$. so it is not important!

Why we compensate the opamp:

opamp input is a symmetric architecture and if you change the symmetry this generates offset and gain temperature drift. the opamp input impedance is base on the substrate, for example for your case is \$10^{12}\:\Omega\$. when you put a resistance in the input, the quiescent current of the input pin generate offset voltage in input and difference of current in two sides generate different behavior in temperature.

When R compensation is important:

- when input_resistance* Input_Offset_Current_max > Voffset or comparable.
- When the source has a high built-in impedance
- If you need a high gain system.
- If drift in temperature is very important even \$1\:\mu\text{V}\$!